# mysqldump to gzip, how to set the extension of the compressed file

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, pipe, gzip

I'm using the following command to dump and compress a database:

```
mysqldump {options} db_name | gzip > db_name.zip
```

and it successfully create a `db_name.zip` archive containing the database dump.

The problem is that the compressed dump file inside the archive is named `db_name.zip.uncompressed`, while I'd like it to be a simple `db_name.sql` instead.

How should I modify my initial command in order to achieve this?

Comment: With gzip reading from STDIN, there is no filename to preserve in the gzip archive. That is, the "file inside the archive" does not have a name. This behavior is entirely independent of mysqldump. e.g. we could replace `mysqldump {options} db_name` with `cat test.txt` and observe the same behavior. (It's a bit odd to assign a suffix of ".zip" to a gzip archive. "zip" archives are different than gzip (RFC 1952) .gz archives).  To have gunzip write a file named `db_name.sql`, the typical name of the archive would have `.gz` suffix appended i.e. `... | gzip > db_name.sql.gz`.  (gzip can retain na

Answer (score 1):

insert **.sql** into the filename like this:

```
$ ls -l

$ mysqldump -uroot -pXXXXX  test data | gzip > data.sql.gz
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 bernd  staff  862 22 Mär 20:48 data.sql.gz

$ gunzip data.sql.gz 

$ ls -l
-rw-r--r--  1 bernd  staff  2464 22 Mär 20:48 data.sql
$
```